# twisted stdio.StandardIO on Windows

Tags: python, windows, twisted

I have Python 2.7 amd64 running on Windows 7 + latest Twisted 12
I have very simple programm which connects stdin/stdout with remote tcp server

```
from twisted.internet import stdio, reactor, protocol
from twisted.protocols import basic

class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory = CFactory()
        self.connector = reactor.connectTCP('remote', 8585, self.factory)

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.connector.transport.write("%s\n" % line)

class Client(basic.LineReceiver):
        def lineReceived(self, line):
                delimiter = '\n'
                print "%s" % line

class CFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
        protocol = Client


def main():
    stdio.StandardIO(Echo())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

On Linux it works just fine. But on Windows my input to stdin is being ignored. So nothing being sent to remote side

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Client(basic.LineReceiver):
    def lineReceived(self, line):
        delimiter = '\n'
        print "%s" % line
```

The `delimiter = '\n'` line here has no useful consequences.  It defines a new name in the local scope of the `lineReceived` function, and then ignores that local name.

What you intended to do, I think, is:

```
class Client(basic.LineReceiver):
    delimiter = '\n'

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print "%s" % line
```

This defines a new attribute of the `Client` class, `delimiter`, which controls how the base class, `basic.LineReceiver`, splits up lines.

However, your example program only defines `Client`, it doesn't actually use it.  So this isn't the cause of the problem.  The cause of the problem is very similar, though.  `Echo` is used to handle standard input, and it does not override the default `LineReceiver` delimiter at all.  The default is `'\r\n'`, which is not the line delimiter used on Windows standard input.

Start off your `Echo` definition like this:

```
class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):
    delimiter = '\n'
```

and I think the program will behave as you want, since Windows uses "\n" to delimit lines on standard input (no Windows machine around to verify that, though, so you might want to double check; if that's **not** the case, a very useful response to make would be to explain what the delimiter **is**; if it is the case, verifying that information would also be a good thing).

Comment: nope. Doesn't work either. The same behaviour. Some windows-specific bug

Comment: My mistake.  I see that `Client` isn't actually even used anywhere in your example, only defined.  Answer updated.

Comment: Doesn't work either. I just want python to send data on Enter press. When I input something and press Enter - nothing happens. But when I Ctrl-c after that I can see "my input" command not found bla-bla-bla in cmd

Comment: Can you determine what newline delimiter Windows uses, as I asked in my updated answer?

Comment: Umm.  Read a line from stdin and look at the line delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

Try dataReceived, it might work.:

```
class Echo(basic.LineReceiver):
...
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.connector.transport.write("%s\n" % data)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows a patch is required to fix the problem of receiving input from Std I/O.
Refer to solution posted to ticket # 2157 on twistedmatrix.com here: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/2157

The solution has several attachments - for individual patches. And there is a consolidated patch file which is an unified diff.

I have a 64-bit Python 2.7.3. running on a Windows 7 64-bit machine with Twisted 12.3.0 and I applied the above unified patch to the _win32stdio.py, _pollingfile.py, conio.py. This allows the input and output to/from Std I/O for IProtocol implementations.